# how to make a webbrowser control go blank in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Initially when the webbrowser is just loaded onto a form , it is blank(ie white color) . 
Once we go to a particular website , is there a way to make it go blank again .

I tried going through the methods , but did not find one that would make this happen . Is there another way or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Give this a try:

`webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");`

Comment: Doesn't work in recent versions. Page displays a Page Not Found error page.

Comment: It is not working for me I have also used the  webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank")); but still not working with IE 11.

Answer (score 13):

You'll need to convert "about:blank" to a uri in order to use BinaryTox1n's answer.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));
```

Comment: `new Uri` - case sensitive :)

Comment: webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank")); not working with IE 11. can you please suggest another way or any settings do i need to change in IE?