# Remove all div elements from string using vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, tags, str-replace, regexp-replace

I want to remove all  elements, including the ones with attributes like `class`, from my string.
I already checked here, so regex is apparently not the answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I currently already have something with regex that replaces all tags from a string (note, I'm never parsing a full HTML document if that matters) and preserves the content: `Regex.Replace(s, "<[^>]*(>|$)", String.Empty)`. However, I just want the `div` tags removed and preserve the content.

So I have:

```
<div class=""fade-content""><div><span>some  content</span></div></div>
<div>some  content</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<span>some  content</span>
some  content
```

I was going the regex path stil, and trying something like: `<div>.*<\/div>`, but that excludes divs with attributes.

How can I remove `div` elements only, using VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One, short and simple, is the following one:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "</?div.*?>", String.Empty)
```

Here is an example:

```
    's simulates your html file
    Dim s As String = "<div class="""" fade-content""""><div><span>some  content</span></div></div>" + Environment.NewLine + "<div>some  content</div>"

    'let's store the result in s1
    Dim s1 As String = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "</?div.*?>", String.Empty)

    'output
    MessageBox.Show(s1)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without regular expressions by using a WebBrowser control. Try the following:

**ExtractDesiredData**:

```
Private Function ExtractDesiredData(html As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim result As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    'create new instance
    Using wb As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser()
        wb.Navigate(New Uri("about:blank"))

        'create reference
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = wb.Document

        'add html to document
        doc.Write(html)

        'loop through body elements
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In doc.Body.All
            If elem.TagName = "DIV" AndAlso Not elem.InnerHtml.Contains("DIV") Then
                Debug.WriteLine($"DIV elem InnerHtml: '{elem.InnerHtml}'")

                'add
                result.Add(elem.InnerHtml)
            End If
        Next
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

**Usage**:

```
Dim html As String = "<div class=""fade-content""><div><span>some  content</span></div></div>"
html &= vbCrLf & "<div>some  content</div>"

Dim desiredData As List(Of String) = ExtractDesiredData(html)
```

**Resources**:

- [how to make a webbrowser control go blank in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779445/how-to-make-a-webbrowser-control-go-blank-in-c)